# CodeIgniter access parent function variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, scope, parent

I have made a script that adds files to a zip (after lots of parsing, etc..) and I have this function:

```
function _add_file($command)
{
    if (!isset($command["source"]) || !isset($command["dest"])) {
        return;
    }

    if (!get_file_info("files/".$command["source"])) {
        return;
    }

    $zip->addFile("files/".$command["source"], $command["destination"]);
}
```

It gives an error because $zip is not defined in _add_file. How can I let _add_file access the $zip defined in the function that calls it (without `_add_file($command, $zip)`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a class variable `var $zip` and access it with `$this->zip`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR? I see what you mean but it doesn't work for some reason now.

Comment: I was just about to write a long update :) Glad you fixed it.